# SQL Server filter zero values in dynamic sentence with pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I am taking a working query in SQL Server and using dynamic pivoting to see a column named `Referencia` with some PC names in the next columns. The idea is to use the SQL sentence to obtain then a bar chart in Grafana.
The SQL sentence that I am using is the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'PCHQ0197,PCHQ0215,PCHQ0272';

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(PC)
                   FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN TABLA_REFERENCIAS TR ON DG.RefId = TR.Id
                   WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PC, ','))
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT Referencia, ' + @cols + '
              FROM
              (
              SELECT PC,
                     TR.Referencia AS Referencia
              FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN TABLA_REFERENCIAS TR ON DG.RefId = TR.Id
              WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL
              ) AS A
              PIVOT
              (
                  COUNT(PC) FOR PC IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) AS P
              ORDER BY Referencia'
EXECUTE(@query);
```

An example of the obtained table is:

| Referencia | PCHQ0197 | PCHQ0215 | PCHQ0272 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 221469-1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 221479-U | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 221519-9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This sentence itself works as expected, but now I would like to filter the resulting table so that I only see those rows of `Referencia` having not zero values in the `PC` columns.

The obtained result should look as follows:

| Referencia | PCHQ0197 | PCHQ0215 | PCHQ0272 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 221469-1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 221479-U | 3 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Why not just add `AND PC IS NOT NULL` to your `WHERE` then?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I changed a little bit the sentence when declaring `@PC`. I already thought about using `IS NOT NULL`, but did not get the expected results.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 19.0.1 version.

Comment: SSMS is just the client software, what is the actual version of SQL Server Database Engine you are using `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Pivot with count() will not return NULL (count() does not return null). You probably want to exclude rows which have all zeroes, 0s,  in the pivoted columns. 0 is not the same as NULL

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU19) (KB5023049) - 15.0.4298.1 (X64)  Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Sure. I am not obtaining NULL values but 0s. I want to exclude those rows.

Comment: One option would be to filter rows before the pivot.. `WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL AND PC IN (‘PCHQ0197’,’PCHQ0215’,’PCHQ0272’) AS A..`

Comment: I receive an error in that new line: `Incorrect syntax near 'PCHQ0197'`

Comment: The single quotes should be escaped (in a string): `SET @query = 'SELECT Referencia, ' +@cols + '   FROM    (  SELECT PC,  TR.Referencia AS Referencia         FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG INNER JOIN TABLA_REFERENCIAS TR ON DG.RefId = TR.Id  WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL   AND PC IN (''PCHQ0197'',''PCHQ0215'',''PCHQ0272'') -- similar values as @PC/@cols but single quoted      ) AS A   PIVOT ...`.

Comment: Another option would be to filter after the pivot `SET @query = 'SELECT Referencia, ' +@cols + '… PIVOT (     COUNT(PC) FOR PC IN (' + @cols + ') ) AS P WHERE checksum('+@cols +')=0 ORDER BY Referencia' `

Comment: Both previous answers helped me. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `WHERE` filter on the values within the dynamic SQL

This is much easier to do if you use a manual pivot using conditional aggregation.

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PC AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'PCHQ0197,PCHQ0215,PCHQ0272';

SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG('
  ' + QUOTENAME(PC) + ' = COUNT(CASE WHEN PC = ' + QUOTENAME(PC, '''') + ' THEN 1 END)', ',')
FROM (
    SELECT PC
    FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG
    INNER JOIN TABLA_REFERENCIAS TR ON DG.RefId = TR.Id
    WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL
      AND PC IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PC, ','))
    ) dg
);

SET @query = '
SELECT
  Referencia, ' + @cols + '
FROM DATOS_GENERALES DG
INNER JOIN TABLA_REFERENCIAS TR ON DG.RefId = TR.Id
WHERE TimeStamp_UTC IS NOT NULL
  AND PC IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@PC, '',''))
GROUP BY Referencia
ORDER BY Referencia;
';

PRINT @query;

EXEC sp_executesql @query
  N'@PC nvarchar(max)',
  @PC;
```

To be honest, it's probably more efficient to use a well-indexed Table-Valued Parameter, rather than relying on `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: Some sintax errors appear in lines 17, 23.

Comment: Should be working now